# Create dynamic fixed-size arrays

Tags: solidity, arrays, struct

Any ideas on how to dynamically create fixed-side arrays that doesn't involve a bunch of if statements?

**EDIT**:

Got this function that needs to produce a fixed-side array which length would depend on the args passed to it. As you can see, it looks a bit ugly with the if statements and it's not that scalable.

```js
struct TokenLiq {
        uint amountIn;
        uint[2] biLiq;
        uint[3] triLiq;
    }

function _calculateTokenAmount(
   uint amountIn_, 
   uint length_
) private returns(TokenLiq memory tokens) 
{
        uint tokenAmount;

        if (length_ == 3) { 
            uint[3] memory amounts;
            amounts[0] = 0;
            amounts[1] = 0;
            amounts[2] = amountIn_;
            tokenAmount = s.tricrypto.calc_token_amount(amounts, true);
            tokens.amountIn = tokenAmount;
            tokens.triLiq = amounts;
        } else if (length_ == 2) {
            uint[2] memory amounts;
            amounts[0] = 0;
            amounts[1] = amountIn_;
            tokenAmount = s.crv2Pool.calc_token_amount(amounts, true);
            tokens.amountIn = tokenAmount;
            tokens.biLiq = amounts;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example or exaplain better? Thank you

Comment: Done ;) @Kerry99

Answer (score 0):

Try this example of smart contract that I created on your piece of code basement:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Test {

    mapping(address => TokenLiq) _liq;

    struct TokenLiq {
        uint amountIn;
        uint[] biLiq;
        uint[] triLiq;
    }

    modifier checkLengthArray(uint _lengthArray, uint _length) {
        require((_lengthArray <= 3 && _lengthArray > 1) &&
                (_length <= 3 && _length > 1), "Error");
        _;        
    }

    function addLiq(uint[] memory amountsArray_, uint length_) public {
        TokenLiq memory t = _calculateTokenAmount(amountsArray_, length_);
        _liq[msg.sender] = t;
    }

    function _calculateTokenAmount(uint[] memory amountsArray_, uint length_) checkLengthArray(amountsArray_.length, length_) private pure returns(TokenLiq memory tokens) 
    {
        uint tokenAmount;
        uint[] memory _amounts = new uint[](length_);
        for(uint i = 0; i < _amounts.length; i++){
            _amounts[i] = amountsArray_[i];
        }

        tokenAmount = s.tricrypto.calc_token_amount(_amounts, true);
        tokens.amountIn = tokenAmount;

        if(_amounts.length == 2)
            tokens.biLiq = _amounts;
        else if(_amounts.length == 3)
            tokens.triLiq = _amounts;
    }

    function _getBiLiq() external view returns(uint[] memory) {
        return _liq[msg.sender].biLiq;
    }

    function _getTriLiq() external view returns(uint[] memory) {
        return _liq[msg.sender].triLiq;
    }

    function _getAmountIn() external view returns(uint) {
        return _liq[msg.sender].amountIn;
    }
}
```

First of all, I change the fixed size of two array `biLiq` and `triLiq` in dynamic size (I don't know if you have possibilities). Then I change the input parameter `amountIn_` in an uint array called `amountsArray`. In this array you must to pass the values in order of index (in your case the value should be: 0,0,amountIn_). Then I created an array dynamic and I set his length with length_ input parameter of `_calculateTokenAmount()` function and I cycle for the length of `amountsArray_` and put into the amountsArray_ value at index `i` into the _amounts array index. Rest of code and functions are simply to understand.
One last thing, I added a `checkLengthArray()` modifier to restrict the size of array to pass to the function. In this case the array length can be only 2 (biLiq) or 3 (triLiq).

Comment: Thanks for the output! The thing is that I couldn't use dynamic-size arrays since those variables were going to be the params of other functions that only took fixed-size. I ended changing my implementation to avoid this situation